# Concatenating Pandas datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, pandas

I have solutions for this question, 2 solutions in fact, but I'm not happy with them. The reason is that the files I'm trying to read have about 12 millions rows, and using these solutions, it takes a huge amount of time to process them. Mainly, the reason is that the solutions are row-by-row operations.

So, I read the file like this:

```
In  [1]: df = pd.read_csv('C:/Projects/NPMRDS/FHWA_TASK2-4_NJ_09_2013_TT.CSV')
         df.head()

Out [1]:     TMC        DATE    EPOCH   Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES    Travel_TIME_PASSENGER_VEHICLES  Travel_TIME_FREIGHT_TRUCKS
         0   103N04152  9252013 211     12                          12                              NaN
         1   103N04152  9262013 0       7                           7                               NaN
         2   103N04152  9032013 177     8                           8                               NaN
         3   103N04152  9042013 176     8                           9                               7
```

My problem is with the **DATE** and **EPOCH** columns. I want to merge them into a single datetime column.

- **DATE** is in '%m%d%Y' format (with the leading zero missing)
- **EPOCH** is 5 minute epoch of a day:

  ```
   Time        EPOCH
   00:00:00 => 0
   00:05:00 => 1
   ...
   ...
   12:00:00 => 144
   12:05:00 => 145
   ...
   ...
   23:50:00 => 286
   23:55:00 => 287
  ```

What I want is something like this:

```
In  [2]: df.head()

Out [2]:     TMC        DATE_TIME           DATE    EPOCH   Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES    Travel_TIME_PASSENGER_VEHICLES  Travel_TIME_FREIGHT_TRUCKS
         0   103N04152  2013-09-25 17:35:00 9252013 211     12                          12                              NaN
         1   103N04152  2013-09-26 00:00:00 9262013 0       7                           7                               NaN
         2   103N04152  2013-09-03 14:45:00 9032013 177     8                           8                               NaN
         3   103N04152  2013-09-04 14:30:00 9042013 176     8                           9                               7
```

Now, I can do this row-by-row as I mentioned earlier by doing either of these three things:

```
In  [3]: df = pd.read_csv('C:/Projects/NPMRDS/FHWA_TASK2-4_NJ_09_2013_TT.CSV',
                 converters={'DATE': lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m%d%Y'),
                             'EPOCH': lambda x: str(datetime.timedelta(minutes = int(x)*5))},
                 parse_dates = {'date_time': ['DATE', 'EPOCH']},
                 keep_date_col = True)
         df.head()

Out [3]:    date_time           TMC         DATE        EPOCH       Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES    Travel_TIME_PASSENGER_VEHICLES  Travel_TIME_FREIGHT_TRUCKS
         0  2013-09-25 17:35:00 103N04152   2013-09-25  17:35:00    12                          12                              NaN
         1  2013-09-26 00:00:00 103N04152   2013-09-26  00:00:00    7                           7                               NaN
         2  2013-09-03 14:45:00 103N04152   2013-09-03  14:45:00    8                           8                               NaN
         3  2013-09-04 14:40:00 103N04152   2013-09-04  14:40:00    8                           9                               7
         4  2013-09-05 09:35:00 103N04152   2013-09-05  09:35:00    10                          10                              NaN
```

In this method I lose the original formatting of **DATE** and **EPOCH**, but it doesn't really affect further computations on the dataframe. Instead of using *converters* as an argument, I could have used *date_parser*. Or, after reading the data, similar to line 1, I could have done something like this:

```
In  [4]: df = pd.read_csv('C:/Projects/NPMRDS/FHWA_TASK2-4_NJ_09_2013_TT.CSV')
         df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime([datetime.datetime.strptime(str(df['DATE'][x]), '%m%d%Y') + datetime.timedelta(minutes = int(df['EPOCH'][x]*5)) for x in range(len(df))])
         df.head()

Out [4]:    TMC         DATE    EPOCH   Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES    Travel_TIME_PASSENGER_VEHICLES  Travel_TIME_FREIGHT_TRUCKS  DATE_TIME
         0  103N04152   9252013 211     12                          12                              NaN                         2013-09-25 17:35:00
         1  103N04152   9262013 0       7                           7                               NaN                         2013-09-26 00:00:00
         2  103N04152   9032013 177     8                           8                               NaN                         2013-09-03 14:45:00
         3  103N04152   9042013 176     8                           9                               7                           2013-09-04 14:40:00
         4  103N04152   9052013 115     10                          10                              NaN                         2013-09-05 09:35:00
```

A more desirable result (don't worry about the column orders), but still row-by-row, and takes a huge amount of time.

Then there are `pandas.to_datetime` and `pandas.to_timedelta`, which run much faster than the methods described above. But I cannot merge the results together without resorting to string functions, which are again mainly row-by-row.
Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out - reduced runtime for me to about 1s (compared to 15s) on 4M rows of test data.

```
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%m%d%Y')
df['EPOCH'] = pd.to_timedelta((df['EPOCH'].astype(int) * 5).astype('timedelta64[m]'))
df['DATE_TIME'] = df['DATE'] + df['EPOCH']
```

Comment: I'm trying to upvote your answer, but I need 15 rep points to do that... Your answer works perfectly, however, I found another similar way to do it in one line of code.
It goes like:

`df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%m%d%Y', box=False) + pd.to_timedelta(df['EPOCH']*5*60, unit='s')`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [chrisb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24981027/3765319) answer, I found a way to do it as well. The trick lies in setting the `box` parameter to `False` in `pandas.to_datetime()`. Like so:

```
df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%m%d%Y', box=False) + pd.to_timedelta(df['EPOCH']*5*60, unit='s')
```

Setting that to `False` returns a `numpy.datetime[64]` array, instead of `pandas.DatetimeIndex`. More information can be found in the `pandas.to_datetime()` documentation. And, `pandas.to_timedelta()` does not work with `unit='m'`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24978394/2) to the question [Concatenating Pandas datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978394/concatenating-pandas-datetime) by the OP [Kartik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3765319/kartik) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>