# Pandas package error or error in my code?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have updated my pandas package using `sudo pip install pandas --upgrade` and I've tried utilizing a `virtualenv` environment but yet I still receive the below error when I try to plot a graph with `pandas` and `matplotlib` I have tested the code through both through the terminal and through the `spyder` IDE.

Here is my data:

```
Call ID Mins    Call Number Name    Join Time

1434600 (01/02) 185         
        000-000-0000    Unspecified 4:59:12 AM
        000-000-0000    Unspecified 4:59:17 AM
        000-000-0000    Unspecified 5:00:36 AM
        000-000-0000    Unspecified 5:02:14 AM
        000-000-0000    Unspecified 5:11:07 AM
        000-000-0000    Unspecified 4:58:11 AM
```

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


def calculate(row):
    """
    Calculates the join date and leave date for the session
    Also give the time till a user was attending session
    """
    date = row['Date']
    join = row['Join Time']
    leave = row['Leave Time']
    year = "2015"
    fmt = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"

    date = date.replace('(', '').replace(')', '') + '/' + year
    join = date + ' ' + join
    leave = date + ' ' + leave

    join = datetime.datetime.strptime(join, fmt)
    leave = datetime.datetime.strptime(leave, fmt)
    time = (leave - join) / 60

    # strangely the seconds giving the value for minutes
    # normally we get seconds then convert to seconds
    mins = time.seconds
    return join, leave, mins


# read the csv file into pandas dataframe
conf_df = pd.read_csv('data/all_report.csv')

# show all the columns inside the dataframe
print list(conf_df.columns.values)

# remove the first line as it contains only summary info
conf_df = conf_df[1:]

# remove the column, doesn't contain any value
# he axis=1 specifier, that means that the application is done at a row,
# rather than a column level.
conf_df = conf_df.drop('Conference Code', 1)

conf_df.dropna(subset=['Call Number'], how='all')

# fill the conference id across the user details
conf_df['Call ID'] = conf_df['Call ID'].fillna(method='ffill')

# remove rows which don't contain the users
conf_df.dropna(subset=['Call Number'], inplace=True)


conf_df["Conference_ID"], conf_df["Date"] = zip(*conf_df["Call ID"].str.split().tolist())

# remove the Call ID column
conf_df = conf_df.drop('Call ID', 1)


# computing all the values necessary for the analysis
conf_df['Join Time'], conf_df['Leave Time'], conf_df['Mins'] = zip(*conf_df.apply(lambda row: calculate(row),axis=1))


print conf_df.head(8)
conf_df
conf_df.groupby(conf_df["Join Time"]).count().plot(kind="bar")
#conf_df.groupby(conf_df["Join Time"].dt.month).count().plot(kind="bar")

conf_df.plot(y=conf_df['Join Time'])

# selecting the months and plotting the bar-graph
months = conf_df.groupby(conf_df["Join Time"].dt.month)
months.size()
months.size().plot("line")

# getting the date time 
days = conf_df.groupby(conf_df["Join Time"].dt.date)
days.size()
days.size().plot("bar")


# selecting the session only on Wednesday, Friday and Saturday
conf_df_wfs = conf_df[(conf_df["Join Time"].dt.weekday == 2) | (conf_df["Join Time"].dt.weekday == 4) | (conf_df["Join Time"].dt.weekday == 5)]
conf_df_wfs.groupby(conf_df["Join Time"].dt.weekday).size().plot("bar")

# saving the pandas dataframe to csv
conf_df.to_csv('data/processed_data.csv')
```

The errors:

```
  File "analyze_data.py", line 68, in <module>
    conf_df.plot(y=conf_df['Join Time'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 3671, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2556, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2370, in _plot
    series = data[y].copy()  # Don't modify
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1963, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2007, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1150, in _convert_to_indexer
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['2015-01-01T23:59:12.000000000-0500' '2015-01-01T23:59:17.000000000-0500'\n '2015-01-02T00:00:36.000000000-0500' ...,\n '2015-11-25T00:06:59.000000000-0500' '2015-11-25T00:16:50.000000000-0500'\n '2015-11-24T23:56:52.000000000-0500'] not in index"
```

Comment: Please consider adding a [mcve]. And I think [pandas can have problems](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+plot+time) with plotting dates, but this might be a different problem. Your last line, the ugly huge date value for the key, might suggest that it's related. Considering the amount of stuff in your code, I wouldn't rush to suspect an error in pandas.

Comment: Your code sadly goes all over the place to do simple things. Perhaps if you streamline it a bit, your problem might resolve itself out. Consider using `pandas.to_datetime()` and `pd.to_timedelta()` instead of your convoluted approach of defining function `calculate()`. If you want help putting together date and time, look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978394/concatenating-pandas-datetime). Maybe after you clean your data correctly, and set the necessary indexes, your issue might be resolved. It is very difficult to help you right now. Sorry.